# Need help in converting verilog module without input & output ports into synthesizable. Because module without input/output ports is not synthesizable

Tags: image, verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, hdl

I created a verilog module for my project, and getting the expected output (but it doesn't has a testbench, it takes required input data by reading a .txt file using `$readmemh`)

But a module without input or output ports cant be synthesized.

Need to synthesize it using **cadence** to get **area, power reports** (Not dumping it on FPGA). If required **another top module** which instantiates this module can also be used.

Need help to make this code synthesizable (Planar and DC outputs are required to be displayed -

**Input** : clk

**Outputs** :
Y_Planar_output, Cb_Planar_output, Cr_Planar_output, Y_DC_output_corner, Y_DC_output_left, Y_DC_output_top.

Any extra input/output ports if required can be used to make it synthesizable)

**Code**

```
module hevc_v6;

//Registers to store file contents and reference buffer for Y, Cb and Cr
reg [7:0] Y_data[0:291];
reg [7:0] Y_ref_buffer[0:34];

reg [7:0] Cb_data[0:82];
reg [7:0] Cb_ref_buffer[0:18];

reg [7:0] Cr_data[0:82];
reg [7:0] Cr_ref_buffer[0:18];

//Reading pixel values from text file
initial $readmemh("Luma_Y_data_16x16.txt", Y_data);
initial $readmemh("Chroma_Cb_data_8x8.txt", Cb_data);
initial $readmemh("Chroma_Cr_data_8x8.txt", Cr_data);

//Registers for Matrix
reg [7:0] Y_luma_matrix [0:15][0:15];
reg [7:0] Cb_chroma_matrix [0:7][0:7];
reg [7:0] Cr_chroma_matrix [0:7][0:7];

//Registers for Planar and DC prediction outputs for Y, Cb and Cr
reg [11:0] Y_Planar_output [0:15][0:15];
reg [11:0] Y_DC_output_corner;
reg [11:0] Y_DC_output_left [1:15];
reg [11:0] Y_DC_output_top [1:15];

reg [11:0] Cb_Planar_output [0:7][0:7];

reg [11:0] Cr_Planar_output [0:7][0:7];

//Extra registers for Planar prediction
//Luma Y
reg [11:0] Y_pred_h [0:15][0:15];
reg [11:0] Y_pred_v [0:15][0:15];

//Chroma Cb
reg [11:0] Cb_pred_h [0:7][0:7];
reg [11:0] Cb_pred_v [0:7][0:7];

//Chroma Cr
reg [11:0] Cr_pred_h [0:7][0:7];
reg [11:0] Cr_pred_v [0:7][0:7];

//Extra registers for DC prediction
reg [12:0] Y_dc_avg;

//Clock initialization
reg clk;
initial clk = 0;
always #5 clk = ~clk;

//Storing pixel values into matrix  
integer x, y, z;

//Luma Y
initial
    for (x=0; x<256; x=x+1)
        Y_luma_matrix [x/16][x%16] = Y_data[x]; 

//Chroma Cb
initial
    for (y=0; y<64; y=y+1)
        Cb_chroma_matrix [y/8][y%8] = Cb_data[y]; 

//Chroma Cr
initial
    for (z=0; z<64; z=z+1)
        Cr_chroma_matrix [z/8][z%8] = Cr_data[z]; 
        
//Ref buffer initialization
integer a, b, c;

//Luma Y
initial 
    for (a=0; a<35; a=a+1)
        //Y_ref_buffer [a] = 'h80;
        Y_ref_buffer [a] = Y_data[256+a];

//Chroma Cb
initial 
    for (b=0; b<19; b=b+1)
        //Cb_ref_buffer [b] = 'h80;
        Cb_ref_buffer [b] = Cb_data[64+b];

//Chroma Cr
initial 
    for (c=0; c<19; c=c+1)
        //Cr_ref_buffer [c] = 'h80;
        Cr_ref_buffer [c] = Cr_data[64+c];

//PLANAR PREDICTION
integer e,f,g,h,i,j;

//Luma Y
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    for (f=0; f<16; f=f+1)  
    begin
        for (e=0; e<16; e=e+1) 
        begin
            Y_pred_h [f][e] = (16-1-e) * Y_ref_buffer[19+f] + (e+1) * Y_ref_buffer[1];
            Y_pred_v [f][e] = (16-1-f) * Y_ref_buffer[3+e] + (f+1) * Y_ref_buffer[2];
            Y_Planar_output [f][e] = (Y_pred_h [f][e] + Y_pred_v [f][e] + 16 ) >> (4+1);                
        end
    end
end

//Chroma Cb
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    for (h=0; h<8; h=h+1)   
    begin
        for (g=0; g<8; g=g+1) 
        begin
            Cb_pred_h [h][g] = (8-1-g) * Cb_ref_buffer[11+h] + (g+1) * Cb_ref_buffer[1];
            Cb_pred_v [h][g] = (8-1-h) * Cb_ref_buffer[3+g] + (h+1) * Cb_ref_buffer[2];
            Cb_Planar_output [h][g] = (Cb_pred_h [h][g] + Cb_pred_v [h][g] + 8 ) >> (3+1);              
        end
    end
end

//Chroma Cr
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    for (j=0; j<8; j=j+1)   
    begin
        for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) 
        begin
            Cr_pred_h [j][i] = (8-1-i) * Cr_ref_buffer[11+j] + (i+1) * Cr_ref_buffer[1];
            Cr_pred_v [j][i] = (8-1-j) * Cr_ref_buffer[3+i] + (j+1) * Cr_ref_buffer[2];
            Cr_Planar_output [j][i] = (Cr_pred_h [j][i] + Cr_pred_v [j][i] + 8 ) >> (3+1);              
        end
    end
end

//DC PREDICTION
integer m,n;

//For only Luma Y
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    Y_dc_avg = (Y_ref_buffer[3] + Y_ref_buffer[4] + Y_ref_buffer[5] + Y_ref_buffer[6] + Y_ref_buffer[7] + Y_ref_buffer[8] + Y_ref_buffer[9] + Y_ref_buffer[10] + Y_ref_buffer[11] + Y_ref_buffer[12] + Y_ref_buffer[13] + Y_ref_buffer[14] + Y_ref_buffer[15] + Y_ref_buffer[16] + Y_ref_buffer[17] + Y_ref_buffer[18] + Y_ref_buffer[19] + Y_ref_buffer[20] + Y_ref_buffer[21] + Y_ref_buffer[22] + Y_ref_buffer[23] + Y_ref_buffer[24] + Y_ref_buffer[25] + Y_ref_buffer[26] + Y_ref_buffer[27] + Y_ref_buffer[28] + Y_ref_buffer[29] + Y_ref_buffer[30] + Y_ref_buffer[31] + Y_ref_buffer[32] + Y_ref_buffer[33] + Y_ref_buffer[34]) >> (4+1);
    
    Y_DC_output_corner = (Y_ref_buffer [19] + 2 * Y_dc_avg + Y_ref_buffer[3] + 2) >> 2;
    
    for (m=1; m<16; m=m+1)
        Y_DC_output_left [m] = (Y_ref_buffer[3+m] + 3 * Y_dc_avg + 2) >> 2;
    for (n=1; n<16; n=n+1)
        Y_DC_output_top [n] = (Y_ref_buffer[19+n] + 3 * Y_dc_avg + 2) >> 2;
end     

endmodule
```

Help is appreciated!

These are the 3 text files, you can copy these data into notepad (notepad++ would be better i feel)

Luma_Y_data_16x16.txt

99  9C  99  96  9C  9A  99  9A  9B  97  99  98  98  98  96  98  9A  9B  9D  9D  9A  9C  99  9A  99  97  9B  98  98  98  9B  9B  9D  9B  9C  9B  9B  9E  97  9A  9A  99  99  9A  9A  98  99  9A  9F  9E  9A  99  9A  9C  9B  9B  9C  9C  9A  9A  99  9A  99  98  9B  9B  9A  99  9B  9E  9D  9E  9C  9B  9C  9A  9B  9A  9B  98  9F  9D  9B  9C  9C  9F  9D  9E  9B  9A  9A  9B  9E  9C  9A  99  A1  A0  9D  A0  9D  9D  9F  9D  9B  9F  9A  9B  9D  9E  9B  9A  9F  A0  A1  9C  9E  9E  9A  9F  9D  9F  9E  9F  9D  9C  A0  9C  9F  A1  A0  9C  9F  9F  9E  9D  9F  A1  9F  9E  9D  9C  9F  9D  A3  A1  A2  A1  9E  A0  A1  9D  9F  9C  A0  9E  9C  9E  9F  9F  A0  9F  A2  9F  A3  9E  9F  9F  A0  9F  A0  A0  A2  A1  A0  9E  A2  A2  A5  A4  A1  9F  9F  A0  A1  9F  9F  A1  A3  A0  9F  A1  A5  A5  A2  A0  A3  A2  9F  A0  A4  A2  A1  9E  9F  A3  9B  9E  A6  A2  A3  A1  A2  A2  A3  A1  A1  A5  A3  A2  A3  A1  9A  A1  A5  A2  A2  A3  A1  A5  A3  A2  A2  A3  A2  A3  A3  A0  A0  9F  A5  A7  A7  A2  A1  A5  A3  A3  A3  9F  A4  A1  A2  A1  A0  9F

98  98  A4  99  96  97  9A  98  9C  9A  97  9A  99  99  9A  98  99  9A  99  9A  99  9D  9D  9B  9E  9F  9E  9F  A1  A1  9F  A3  A2  A5  A2

Chroma_Cb_data_8x8.txt

84  84  85  85  85  86  86  86  84  84  85  85  85  86  86  86  84  84  84  85  85  85  85  85  83  83  84  84  84  84  83  84  84  84  83  84  84  83  83  83  82  82  83  83  84  83  83  83  81  81  82  83  83  82  82  82  81  81  82  83  82  82  82  82

86  88  80  86  86  86  87  88  86  85  86  83  83  83  83  83  83  82  80

Chroma_Cr_data_8x8.txt

68  68  69  69  69  68  68  68  68  68  69  69  69  68  68  68  68  68  68  69  69  68  68  68  68  67  68  6A  69  68  68  68  6A  6A  6A  69  69  68  68  68  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  69  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6B  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A  6A

68  66  6C  69  69  68  68  68  67  66  67  68  68  69  69  69  6A  6A  6A

Comment: @Mikef which ever is easy. I just want to synthesize it in cadence (get area, power, timing reports. Not dumping it on FPGA. Creating a different top level module which instantiates hevc_v6 is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of synthesis concerns for the OP and how to address them:

- The large number of bits created by adding module ports may be an issue.  The number of module ports is greater than the number of IO pins than any physical FPGA has.  Synthesis targets a specify physical device than has finite physical resources.  Very large FPGAs have several hundred IO pins (I have never seen one advertised with 1000 user IO pins, if one exists it would be in the .1 percentile of all devices on the market).  If this line of code becomes a port `[11:0] Y_Planar_output [0:15][0:15]`, synthesis will attempt to allocate 12X16X16 = 3072 FPGA pins to connect to the ports.  Since no physical FPGA has that many IO pins synthesis will fail.    The design in the post would have several very large ports like this.  There is no chance the number of ports needed will fit in a physical FPGA (in other words synthesis will fail).

  Vivado synthesis has an build option called `out_of_context`, which tells the tool that the module being synthesized is an internal module and not to infer IO pins.
  I did a internet search and did not find such an option in Cadence synthesis.  You will need to research this.

  If Cadence does not have such an option then the code must be modified such that the memories are accessed one address at a time.  The corresponding port size would be 12-bits rather than thousands of bits.  The re-write could involve state machine controllers to load and unload the memories.
- Change internal variables (the ones listed in the OP that need to change) to ports like this (be sure to remove the local corresponding variable):

  ```
        module hevc_v6
          (
          input clk,
          output reg [11:0] Y_Planar_output [0:15][0:15],
          output reg [11:0] Cb_Planar_output [0:7][0:7],
          // more ports
          );
  ```
- Get rid of the internal driver on the clock `always #5 clk = ~clk`
- Change the `initial` blocks that have `for` to synchronous always blocks like this:

  ```
  always @(posedge clk)
    for (x=0; x<256; x=x+1)
        Y_luma_matrix [x/16][x%16] = Y_data[x]
  ```
- There are a couple of initial blocks whose output goes nowhere.  Decide what to do with these (bring them out the ports?, get rid of them, change to synchronous always blocks?).  For example:

```
    initial
      for (z=0; z<64; z=z+1)
        Cr_chroma_matrix [z/8][z%8] = Cr_data[z]
```

- In this line and similar `Cr_chroma_matrix [z/8][z%8] = Cr_data[z]`
  The / operator and the % operators will not synthesize to the math functions as expected.
  Those operators can be used on parameters and things that are known and don't change at elaboration time only in RTL.
  For the `/`8 (divide by 8) operator, use shift to the right by 3 places.
  For `%`8 (mod 8) operator, drop the low three bits.  This trick works for mod powers of 2.
- The `$readmemh()` call
  If you are using a tool which does not support $readmemh(), then change the $readmemh() + file combination to a RTL ROM using a case statement.  Search 'Verilog ROM' for more.
- This block of code may infer more multipliers than the physical device has.    I see at least 16X16X2 = 512 multipliers in this block.  You may need to re-write it to do one multiply (or a reasonable number relative to the number of multiplies the device has) at a time.

```
    // Chroma Cr
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
      for (j=0; j<8; j=j+1) begin
        for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
          // infers a lot of multiplies             
        end
      end
```

Keep in mind that synthesis targets a physical device with finite resources; write the RTL to model within the limits of those resources.

If these concerns are addressed, then the design should synthesize.

Write a testbench if you want to understand how the changed design works.  The timing will be different for initial blocks with for loops replaced by synchronous processes.